# Drawing one rectangle on another.

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I want to draw one rectangle on another, for example first is filled with Black color and second is filled with triangle, how to create one rectangle with black background and triangle on it? I'm writing windows store app in C#, using uncle google there is some examlpes using

`Graphics g = new Graphics();`

But there isnt `Graphics` object in windows store app, and `Rectangle.Fill` method is replacing content. What do I nead to do?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't a `Graphics` class in WinRT XAML because that belongs to dinosaur winforms.

You must learn [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) in order to create UIs on XAML-based technologies such as WinRT (AKA Windows Store or Metro) or WPF.

XAML is a declarative, XML-based language that is used to describe an object graph. UIs in XAML-based technologies are *defined* using XAML and then interacted with via [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) as opposed to the traditional too-much-code-for-everything procedural winforms approach.

This is how you do a Black rectangle with a Triangle inside in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Black"/>
    <Polygon Points="50,0 0,100 100,100" 
             Fill="White" Margin="10"
             Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thans, but there is posibility that I will get one black rectanlgle and other will be filled with hat that is .png file. How to do that?

Comment: PS. and as I wrote i nead to create one rectangle not rectangle and polygon. I will nead to save it as one graphic file.

Comment: @BartekZiółkowski you can either use an `Image` control, or an `ImageBrush` to fill your polygons. Your question is not clear enough and you have not specified that, that's why I answered with the simplest example.

Comment: @BartekZiółkowski If you need something different just change the XAML to reflect what you need. My explanation is about the basic approach to create UIs in XAML based technologies, as you seem to be looking for `Graphics` stuff which does not exist in current technologies.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry for not being spebyfic, my main goal is to combine two rectangles in to one and save it as *.jpg file.